# How to deal Semantic Versioning on Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, semantic-versioning

I'm beginning on Jenkins in my work place. We use semantic versioning with Teamcity and I want to implement the same on Jenkins. My problem appears when I store the artifacts in builds folder ($JENKINS_HOME/jobs/$JOB_NAME/builds/$BUILD_NUMBER) because Jenkins use only the build_number to create the folder for build so when I have to reset de Build_number the future artifacts will be stored in the folder of previous builds.

> For example:
>
> *I have build 1.3.1_develop.1 stored, when I reset Build_Number the next build should be 1.3.2_develop.1 and it should be stored in the
>   folder 1 of build 1.3.1_develop.1*

My question is if someone could explain me how to deal with automatic semantic versioning on jenkins because we reset the build number we increase the mayor, minor and patch number.

Jenkins Version: 2.89.4
Jobs--> We use jobs to compile Vuejs for front and to deploy back with python (If this helps)

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Is your build system deterministic? Does it always produce exactly the same output for each fixed set of inputs?

Comment: No, my build system create the folder with the Build_number is always increasing but I reset the number to begin again. (Jenkins does in that way)

Answer (score 6):

First thing I notice is you are not using semantic versioning correctly. `1.3.1_develop.1` should be `1.3.1-develop+1`. Build metadata should always be preceded by the plus '+' symbol and is not factored into the SemVer sort order.

Second, build number is never "reset", it might roll-over eventually, but it should never be reset. A build number that does not indicate the machine performing the build is also generally useless unless there can only ever be one.

Basically, there's no concept of a build number in semantic versioning. The standard specifies the syntax for build meta data, but is completely neutral on what might be included. Build numbers are generally useless at the level of semantic versioning. They have their uses for preventing directory collisions in CI build systems and even provide a unique identifier for some product lines (Windows for instance), particularly where semantic versioning is not in use (Windows again).

I recommend using a SHA-1 or better hash of the build inputs (Git commit Id for instance) in the build meta tag in addition to any build counter, and use that for your output directory name. You can still use a monotonic counter on your prerelease tags as well, but you would have to create a build output directory name that includes the entire semver string in order to maintain uniqueness.

Third, your build machine is the worst place to archive your build artifacts! Build automation can and does go horribly wrong from time to time. Your build system should not have access to your archive of build artifacts. When your build and initial smoke testing is completed, it should signal a process running on a completely different machine to move the artifacts off the build machine to a more secure location. No process running on the build system should have write access to your archive of build artifacts.

Comment: First of all thanks for your answer. We also store the success builds in other place in a google machine, do you know if there is any way to link in jenkins build that version copied in the google machine?? I want to access to the lasts versions in jenkins, I don't know if that is the correct way to do it but in Teamcity we can access the 20 last builds. You talk about to use a counter and that should help me, but there is a way to increase that counter automatically?? sorry if a ask "dumb" questions but jenkins is new for me and i'm really confused with it

Comment: Jenkins is just another random CI environment I don't want to know anything about. I can help you with SemVer and general CI processes/patterns, but not the details. If Jenkins doesn't have built-in support for what you want to do, you can always write a script for it. Counters are fairly simple to implement with a number in a file.

Answer (score 2):

There is a tool `GitVersion` which does what you want and it can be integrated with Jenkins or other CI providers.

https://gitversion.net/docs/reference/build-servers/jenkins